# Musical pitch count in a for loop using python

Tags: python

Write a program that finds and prints the frequencies of all the musical notes between A440 andA880. Using the twelfth root of two. Here is my current code.

```
2**(1.0/12) is the twelfth root.
```

from math import sqrt

```
i=0
a=440
a2=(a*(2**(1.0/12.0)))
for i in range(12):
    print (a2)
    a2=a2+i
    i=i+1
```

And this code gives me the output of.

```
466.1637615180899
466.1637615180899
467.1637615180899
469.1637615180899
472.1637615180899
476.1637615180899
481.1637615180899
487.1637615180899
494.1637615180899
502.1637615180899
511.1637615180899
521.1637615180899
```

However the output I need is

```
440.0
466.163761518
493.883301256
523.251130601
554.365261954
587.329535835
622.253967444
659.255113826
698.456462866
739.988845423
783.990871963
830.60939516
880.0
```

What does my code not have???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your maths is wrong

```
n=440

while (n<=880):
    print n
    n=n*(2**(1.0/12.0))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, However i also need it to print 440.

Comment: @Jake then just move the `print n` up to before the `n=n*...`

Comment: And after you move `print n`, change `n<880` to `n<=880` so that you also get 880 printed.

Comment: changed in line with comments.  Thanks to @PaulH also.  I recommend csound http://www.csounds.com/resources/downloads/ even though I haven't used it for ten years :)

Comment: `n=<880` is not valid python.  It should be `n<=880`